# I'm trying getting an error when trying to integrate Google Sign In to my Android app: Cannot Resolve Symbol GoogleSignIn

Tags: android

I'm trying to integrate Google Sign In to my Android up but i'm getting an error that the symbol GoogleSignIn cannot be resolved: https://snag.gy/R2Mg3L.jpg

Here is the code and Gradle files for the project; I'm following the instructions provided by Google at: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/

```
package com.example.GSTest;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;

public class loginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
    // profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    // Build a GoogleSignInClient with the options specified by gso.
    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);


    Button gButton = findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    gButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v){

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.sign_in_button:
            signIn();
            break;
        // ...
    }

}

private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}


//end of main class
}
```

Gradle (Project):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to         
all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Gradle (Module):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.GSTest"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
core:3.0.1'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
```

Comment: Are you just setting up Google play services for the first time, or you've copied code into your project without having the dependencies?

Comment: Sorry about the image; GoogleSignin is imported but it gives me the same error: Cannot resolve symbol GoogleSignIn.
GoogleSignInOptions imported fine with no errors though.

Complete source:  https://pastebin.com/f1EzBsEL
i've added the required dependencies too per: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in?configured=true

Comment: Please do not use pastebin either. Provide a [mcve] of your code within the question itself. You can find the edit link above the comments here

Comment: Most importantly, add your Gradle file. Which version of `play-services-auth` do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like all import problems, check your dependencies.

You're trying to use code requiring at least the [11.6.0 release of Google Play](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#november_6_2017_-_version_1160)

> Added the GoogleSignInClient and GoogleSignIn classes. GoogleSignInClient provides the entry point for interacting with the Google Sign In API.

Update the version in your Gradle file

Comment: K, I have attached the Gradle file(s) above.

Comment: `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` should be **outside** the dependencies, and `compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.2'` should not be in that Gradle file

Answer (score -1):

You need to import the package that contains GoogleSignIn. I assume you're using [this one](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignIn).

Comment: import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn has been added but I get an error that the symbol GoogleSignIn cannot be resolved. I'm not sure why because
 import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions works fine.