# I encountered the error "Cannot resolve symbol 'mGoogleSignInClient'" when trying to incorporate Google SignIn using Firebase

Tags: java, android, android-studio, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication

I am using https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin to add google sign to my app but have been unable die to the error "Cannot resolve symbol 'mGoogleSignInClient'". I have added the SignIn Activity followed by Gradle file details below.

Sign-In Activity:

```
    package com.ccc.iima_app.activity;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import com.ccc.navigationdrawer.R;
    import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
    import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
    public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
            GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id)).requestEmail().build();
            mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
        }
    }
```

Project Level Gradle

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
    
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    
            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }
    
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
    }
    
    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

App Gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 28
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.ccc.iima_app"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 28
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    
        androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })

        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
        implementation 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'
        // Glide image library
        implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
        implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    
        implementation 'androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.2.0'

        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.2'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:18.0.0'
    }
    configurations {
        compile.exclude group: "junit", module: "junit"
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I have tried StackOverflow solution in:[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47298814/im-trying-getting-an-error-when-trying-to-integrate-google-sign-in-to-my-androi) but still have been unable to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Go above your oncreate() method and this line of code :

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private mGoogleSignInClient GoogleSignInClient;  // add this line of code 
        private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
            GoogleSignInOptions gso = new 
 
GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id)).requestEmail().build();
            mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean `private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;`? Because I get the same error "Cannot resolve symbol 'mGoogleSignInClient'" with your suggestion

Comment: Yeah , how can you screenshot the code please so that i can understand better how is it working for you and also make sure you import it

Comment: I am unable to add a photo in the comment section.

Comment: You can upload it here https://imgur.com/ , and then paste the photo generated link